# How can I sequentially execute code in CUDA via numba?

Tags: cuda, gpu, numba

I would like to execute cuda threads in sequence. For example,
[image]

in the above figure, I would like the value indexed as [thread_id, j] to be fed sequentially, i.e., array[1,2] will be given a value only when array[0,0],array[0,1],array[0,2] are given, etc.

The way that I can think of is to set a global array, and continously retrieve the value of array[0,3]. When array[0,3] is given, I can feed array[1,2].

However, this fails with the following code:

```
import math
import numpy as np
from numba import cuda

@cuda.jit
def keep_max(global_array,array):
        thread_id = cuda.grid(1)
        if thread_id<N:

            # loop through other elements in global_array
            for j in range(thread_id+1, N):

                # consistently read values from array
                for _ in range(1000): # or while True:

                    # for thread_id == 0, just execute
                    if thread_id==0:
                        cuda.atomic.add(array,(thread_id,j), 1)
                        break

                    # for thread_id>0
                    else: 

                        # if j reaches the last number of global_array
                        # just execute
                        if j == N-1:
                            cuda.atomic.add(array,(thread_id,j), 1)
                            break
                        else:  

                            # check if the previous thread_id, i.e., thread_id - 1
                            # finishes the execution of combination [thread_id-1,j+1]
                            if array[thread_id-1,j+1]>0:
                                cuda.atomic.add(array,(thread_id,j), 1)
                                break


N = 10
global_array = np.arange(N)
array = np.zeros([N,N])

# Configure the blocks
threadsperblock = 64
# configure the grids
blockspergrid = (N + (threadsperblock - 1)) // threadsperblock

print(global_array)
keep_max[blockspergrid, threadsperblock](global_array,array)
print(array)


output:

[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
[[0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

The expected output should be:

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
[[0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Another approach that I can think of is to use `cuda.syncthreads()`, here is the code:

```
import math
import numpy as np
from numba import cuda

@cuda.jit
def keep_max(global_array,array):
        thread_id = cuda.grid(1)
        if thread_id<N:

            # j starts from thread_id + 1
            j = thread_id + 1

            # loop through other elements in global_array
            for i in range(2*N-1):

                if i>2*thread_id:
                    if j<N:
                        cuda.atomic.add(array, (thread_id,j), 1)
                    j+=1
                    cuda.syncthreads()
                else:
                    cuda.syncthreads()

N = 10
global_array = np.arange(N)
array = np.zeros([N,N])

# Configure the blocks
threadsperblock = 64
# configure the grids
blockspergrid = (N + (threadsperblock - 1)) // threadsperblock

print(global_array)
keep_max[blockspergrid, threadsperblock](global_array,array)
print(array)
```

output:

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
[[0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

This is of course working. However, if the size of global_array is larger than the number of GPU cores, when thread_id> number of GPU cores, the execution will undergo syncthreads() for many unecessary times. This is timing taking!!

Meanwhile, the serialization between blocks are not possible.

I have three questions:

1. Why the above first code fails when I used atomic operation?
2. Do we have any better ways to implement this?
3. For the first approach, how can I serialize between blocks?

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Why the above code fails?

Because the CUDA execution model makes no guarantees about the order in which threads run, and your assumption about the order of execution is likely to *never* be true. Also all the memory transactions in your code are non-atomic, so the pseudo spinlock you seem to be trying to implement cannot work either.

> 2. Do we have any cleaver[sic] ways to implement this?

No. There is no way to impose execution order in Numba CUDA in the way you require.

Comment: There is of course a way to implement this. Please see the edited version. However, I followed your suggestion and used atomic operations, and the first approach still does not working. Meanwhile, the second approach is a bit slow, which is not what I wanted.

Comment: Your second approach has illegal use of syncthreads.  syncthreads may be used in conditional code only if the condition evaluates identically across the threadblock.  Furthermore, syncthreads only imposes ordering within a threadblock, so your method will not be usable to impose order between threads in different threadblocks.

Comment: @RobertCrovella, Yes, you are right, the serialize between blocks are not possible, but do you know how to do it? Even if it is illegal, it seems working a little bit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54595609/numba-support-for-cuda-cooperative-block-synchronization-python-numba-cuda-gri

Comment: @RobertCrovella I have written one based on the idea of global array as an answer. Can you have a look and make a comment?